# Postgresql check insert input

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert

I'm making a database with **PostgreSQL**. In one of the attributes in a tables it should be possible to `insert` numbers: **"+"** and **"-"**, but no other chars like **"A"**, **"B"** or **"!"**.

Is it possible to check the input when I'm using the `INSERT INTO` function?
I don't know because I'm just a beginner in `Postgre` and didn't find a solution in the internet.

Thanks if anybody knows an answer!

Comment: It could even be done with a check-constraint using a regexp.(or just use one of the numeric datatypes) No triggers needed. see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtable.html (under: CHECK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a trigger, you could use a [CHECK constraint](http://%20postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtable.html) on the column's value. (or even make it a domain or type)

```
CREATE TABLE meuk
        ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , thefield varchar CHECK (thefield SIMILAR TO e'[0-9\+\-]+' )
        );

INSERT INTO meuk(thefield) VALUES ('1234');
INSERT INTO meuk(thefield) VALUES ('+1234');
INSERT INTO meuk(thefield) VALUES ('-1234');
INSERT INTO meuk(thefield) VALUES ('-1234a'); -- this one should fail

SELECT * FROM meuk;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps a lot.